# update_url in manifest file disable my chrome extension

Tags: javascript, xml, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have an chrome extension which is hosted on my server, i have kept an update.xml file with proper parameter.when i create two version of my extesnion 1.0.,2.0 and install 1.0 and upload 2.0 on the server at lets say myusrl/plugi/myext.crx with myusrl/plugin/update.xml ( have a version as 2.0). it does allow the user to update extension to 2.0 but the option of enabling this extension is disabled( cant check the checkbox).

on a weird side i was able to enable my extension till day before yesterday.

part manifest.json is:

```
   "web_accessible_resources": [
    "*.png"
     ],
  "update_url": "http://myurl/plugin/updates.xml",
  "icons": {
    "128": "icon-128.png"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "nativeMessaging",
    "downloads",
    "tabs"  ]
}
```

if i remove update_url link from the manifest then i can enable my intalled extension otherwise not.

updates.xml is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<gupdate xmlns='http://www.google.com/update2/response' protocol='1.0'>
  <app appid=<ID>>
    <updatecheck codebase='http://myurl/plugin/myext.crx' version='2.0' />
  </app>
</gupdate>
```

Has it been disbaled in latest chrome? or some other issue?

Comment: Did you come up with any solution?

Answer (score 2):

It's been disallowed to self-host extensions [a long time ago](http://blog.chromium.org/2015/05/continuing-to-protect-chrome-users-from.html), with the exception of enterprise policy installs.

You didn't mention your OS, as this change affected Chrome on different OSes at different time, but I guess by now it's globally banned.

Comment: Its Mac, but its blocked on Windows as well.

Comment: On a Mac, it may be easier to use enterprise install policies (on Windows, a domain membership is required).